# Does it follow that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{n\#} = e$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, primorial

In the Wikipedia article on [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial), in the [Characteristics Section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial#Characteristics), it is stated:

$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{n\#} = e$$

This sounds reasonable to me.  There is a footnote that references an [article](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa42/aa4242.pdf) in French.  I read through the article but could not find the argument establishing the above result.  I am not fluent in French.

Is this claim correct?  If so, does it follow from the [Prime Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)?  Does it follow from the article referenced?

I would be very interested in understanding the outline of the proof.

Comment: If $\theta$ is the [first Chebyshev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) then $\log (n\# ) = \theta (n) = n + o(n)$ by PNT.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Very clear.  :-)  So that $n\# = e^{n + o(n)}$