# Reasoning about limits related to the prime number theorem

Tags: limits, logarithms, factorial, primorial

From the [Prime Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), it [follows that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4491124/48606):
$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{n\#} = e$$

One of the standard definitions of $e$ as found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#Asymptotics) is that:

$$e = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$$

Based on this, would it be valid to conclude that:

$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!n\#}} = 1$$

Comment: Limit of product is product of limits if they exist.

Comment: Thanks for confirming!  I thought that was reasonable.